# Unexplained warning when reading a '.bmp' file in matlab GUIDE

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, steganography

I have written a matlab file(.m) for performing stegnography for my final year project.

I designed a GUI for the project using GUIDE in matlab.

The program works just fine when run it in a script mode but it gives the following error when i run it in GUIDE mode:

> Warning: The image file directory at offset position 38 has zero entries and has been ignored

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

BMP file? of JPG/TIFF file?

Sounds to me like you have a corrupt image header; see also [this thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/30046-corrupt-image) over at MATLAB Answers.

You could use a simple `warning('off', warnId);` to supress the warning, because it does not affect the correct functioning of your program, but it might confuse your users.

Personally, I'd not suppress the warning, but rather put it like so:

```
%// do your operations here

%// directly after the operation issuing the warning, do this: 
[warnMsg,warnID] = lastwarn;
if strcmpi(warnID, 'known_ID_of_your_warning')
    warndlg(...
        getReport(MException(warnID,warnMsg), 'extended', 'hyperlinks', 'on'), ...
        'Possible file corruption detected'); 
end
```

It looks a lot more professional, but still warns your users of any potential problems that are simply beyond the control of the application.

**NOTE**: I don't know any of the details, but this approach might fail in some situations (for example, it might be possible that more than one warning is issued, but these are internally suppressed (see why that's bad practice?)). In that case, `lastwarn` can't be trusted. You'd then need to use the following (undocumented) construction:

```
%// change warning into error...
warnSts = warning('error', warnID);

%// ...so that it can be caught:
try

    %// ... do operations here

catch ME
    warndlg(...
        getReport(ME, 'extended', 'hyperlinks', 'on'), ...
        'Possible file corruption detected'); 
end
warning(warnSts);
```

Problem there is that execution of the throwing application is stopped *immediately* after the warning is issued; the operation is terminated prematurely and will thus not have completed its task. So then you'd need to do the following inside the `catch`:

- suppress the warning:

  ```
  warning(warnSts);    
  warnSts = warning('off', warnID);
  ```
- repeat the throwing operation
- repeat all operations that should follow it

Which is far from ideal, so if it is at all possible to avoid, use the former method. Just experiment a bit and find which suits your needs.

Comment: @AneeshK: the image isn't, but it's header seems to be.

Comment: @AneeshK: In the end it's up to you if you want to bother your users with this information. Most browsers and image display programs don't bother, but more professional applications certainly do.

Comment: Thank you for a very informative answer. I will try with a different file format and post my experience. I didn't understand your question '_BMP file? of JPG/TIFF file?_'